# Python - Regex to find items recursively

Tags: regex, recursion

First I want to find all lines that has a string 'xyz' in a file  - Im doing this with

Sample file:

```
This is about me. 
My name is xyz and I live in USA. 
There is also a restaurant called xyz in my city.
The food at the xyz is yummy check out their menu. 
The restaurant is 5 miles from my home.
```

---

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    pattern = re.compile('xyz', re.IGNORECASE)
    for line in file1:
        if pattern.search(line):
            print(line)
```

So the output is:

```
My name is xyz and I live in USA. 
There is also a restaurant called xyz in my city.
The food at the xyz is yummy check out their menu.
```

---

In addition I also need to match on the word 'restaurant' " only if it exists " in the output lines, and find all lines that contain that 'restaurant' in the same file. So the end output should be

```
My name is xyz and I live in USA. 
There is also a restaurant called xyz in my city.
The food at the xyz is yummy check out their menu. 
The restaurant is 5 miles from my home.
```

Comment: Do you really mean "line" or do you mean "sentence", because what you've added to your question is all on the same "line".

Comment: are you actually trying to do Natural Language Parsing? not to dissuade you, but doing so is its own field of science (with exciting and high-quality software packages for doing so), and Regular Expressions are not sufficient to meaningfully parse undirected English text because its Grammar is not "Regular"

Comment: @MatB - Yes, I mean sentence. I tried to display that as a paragraph.. but formatting may have put everything in 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we write your sample text as paragraphs ie. one line which will be multiline because of word wrap but not containing carriage return or line end then we can capture 2 words at the same time as follows **if they are always in the same order**.

```
^.*xyz.*restaurant.*$
```

If they could be in either order we need to use 2 positive look aheads.

```
^(?=.*xyz)(?=.*restaurant).*$
```